# How to suffice the following requirement through Query in HANA SP12

Tags: sql, hana

I've a requirement where I want to show the count of customers shopping in combination of particular formats as follows.

```
         Format A   Format B    Format C
Format A    10       20          30
Format B    20       30          40
Format C    30       40          50
```

For example in the following format.

Desired output:

> The count of customers shopping in Format A alone is 10.
>
> The count of customers shopping in Format A and B is 20.
>
> The count of customers shopping in Format A and C is 30.

So on and so forth.

How can this be done using a query ?

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough information.  What does your data look like?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Data is basically customer_no wise format codes where a customer may shop in multiple formats. We have to find the count of customers visiting in a combination of format. Like I've mentioned in the comment. Dataset can be something like select  distinct customer_no,format from customers_table;

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to clearly understand your requirement, but I assumed that your data looks as follows:

```
TXT      | Format A |Format B  | Format C
----------------------------------------
Format A | 10       | 20       | 30
Format B | 20       | 30       | 40
Format C | 30       | 40       | 50
```

Now if you want to pivot this table to display values for each combination without duplicates, you can use logic like this:

```
SELECT
    'A' || CASE WHEN RIGHT("TXT",1) = 'A' THEN '' ELSE RIGHT("TXT",1) END  AS "FORMAT" ,
    "Format A" AS "OUTPUT"
FROM
    "YOUR_TABLE"

    UNION

SELECT
    'B' || CASE WHEN RIGHT("TXT",1) = 'B' THEN '' ELSE RIGHT("TXT",1) END,
    "Format B" AS "OUTPUT"
FROM
    "YOUR_TABLE"                 
WHERE
    "TXT" != 'Format A'

    UNION

SELECT
    'C' || CASE WHEN RIGHT("TXT",1) = 'C' THEN '' ELSE RIGHT("TXT",1) END,
    "Format C" AS "OUTPUT"
FROM
    "YOUR_TABLE"
WHERE
    "TXT" NOT IN ('Format A',   'Format B')
;
```

And output will look as follows:

```
FORMAT  | OUTPUT
A       | 10
AB      | 20
AC      | 30
B       | 30
BC      | 40
C       | 50
```